# Why did Microsoft decide to hide Hibernate option?

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

I used to hibernate my laptop when it was installed with Windows 7. When I update to Windows 10, the option was missing from Start Menu, and I was able to re-enable it after searching using Google. What makes me curious is, why was it hidden by default? Does hibernating have bad effect or something?

Comment: Actually from windows 8 "shut down" action is not a complete shut down, making hibernation somewhat redundant

Comment: FWIW, the option had been hidden even back in Windows XP...